# What does "the" specify in the given sentence?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

Sentence - "The" healthy food is important for people.

What does "the" specify? Does it specify a particular food which is healthy as "food" is the head noun. If it specifies a particular type of food which is healthy, then, what is the need of putting "the" ?

or It specifies a particular type of "healthy food"?

Comment: The sentence you're asking about isn't idiomatic; as a native speaker, I can't think of any non-contrived situation where "the healthy food is important for people" would sound natural.

Comment: @verbose with respect, I actually can think of one, but it needs context. It's in my answer.

Comment: Is this sentence invented by you? If not, please tell us IN the question the source and if you can, also provide the link. Context is hugely important in any language but even more so in English.

Comment: Please read the site's guidelines for making an interesting, useful and detailed question: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please The fact that this is your 8th question in a row about definite articles tells me not only are you interested by its grammar but you are still struggling in understanding how and when to use the definite article.

Comment: The sentence is about healthy food in general being important, so there should be no article here.  Delete "the" to fix it.

Comment: @Jesse your answer focuses on “the healthy food”. I maintain that “the healthy food is important for people” sounds unidiomatic as a sentence.

Comment: @verbose It indeed sounds that way all by itself. When I hear it, I presume either 1. it is grammatically incorrect or 2. it has a context such as this, 1 being the more likely.

Comment: When hearing this, English learners need to know the meaning implied if it is not taken to be incorrect. Such an implied meaning does in fact exist, and knowing about that is an important part of learning and understanding English.

Comment: That's why translations/questions require context.

Answer (score 0):

It means "the healthy food *option*".

From [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/definite-articles/):

> the word the is used to refer to specific things/groups or to particular things/groups that have been ***already identified***

In my ESL teaching, I often explain it to mean that "we already know which" when we say "the".

Here, "healthy food" seems to be one of several choices. This is because "*the* healthy food" has already been identified. So, we already know which *the healthy food* is.

Already identified:

> *the* healthy food (as opposed to *the unhealthy food*)

Not yet identified:

> healthy food

In context:

Q: **Do you want chicken Caesar salad with grape juice or pizza with cola?**

A: **I want *the healthy food*.** (implying the chicken Caesar salad)

---

*If "the healthy food" is not part of a conversation or context with different options for food that we have already identified, then this sentence would be grammatically incorrect.*

Comment: Although I agree with the sentiment (salad is possibly healthier than pizza and coke), I might also feel that it's a bit 'preachy' to express the feeling in that way, and furthermore, I'm a vegetarian.

Comment: There is no indication that the OP found this sentence in the internet. Without  the context, we shouldn't be guessing why the article was used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'm not guessing, merely presenting a context where it could be correct. For a learner, such context would explain what it could mean.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I heat healthy myself, but I don't preach. That said, it is hard to use the word "healthy" in relation to food without coming across as preachy.

Comment: In the context you provided, it would work but the original sentence is "**The healthy food** *is important for people*" It's a general statement, at least it reads like one, and I would not use the definite article there or in a sentence which claims [*Music is a balm for the soul*](https://www.searchquotes.com/search/Music_Is_A_Balm_To_The_Soul/) There are of course  situations where the article would be appropriate e.g. “Radiohead, The Smiths and The Cure  represented **the music** of the 1980s and 90s” but when we speak about things in general the definite article is not required.